# oracle 11gR2 dbms_report.build_report_reference_varg parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

Guys I just noticed that in package specification of `dbms_report` there is a function that looks like

```
FUNCTION build_report_reference_varg(
component_name   IN VARCHAR2,
report_name      IN VARCHAR2,
id_param_val     ...)
 RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

I wonder for what do the "three dots" stand in `id_param_val` parameter? What it does and how is it used?

Comment: PSOUG has it showing as 'UNDEFINED' type, but is a param array.

Comment: @Andrew I could not find any information in documentation, do You know if there's a documented description to this?

Comment: It was not shown in the docs and a search on metalink came up blank as well. http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_report.html has some details but sparse.

Comment: Look at the spec for 'DBMS_REPORTS' - the comment before the definition of 'BUILD_REPORT_REFERENCE_VARG' shows how to call this procedure. `BUILD_GENERIC_TAG` (undocumented function in the same package) also uses the `...` parameter notation. Best of luck.